# Conditional Table Join In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named '**Task**' with fields (Id int, TaskName nvarchar, AssigneeType int, AssigneeId int).

**AssigneeType** can contain **3** int values pointing to specific tables. (0 = User, 1 = Group, 2 = Location)

- User, Group, Location are the tables

AssigneeId contains the Id of record in the table pointed by AssigneeType.

**Problem Area**

I want to extract all tasks by joining task table with the table pointed by AssigneeType.

If AssigneeType contains 0, I need to join Task table with User table.

If AssigneeType contains 1, I need to join Task table with Group table.

If AssigneeType contains 2, I need to join Task table with Location table.

Basically I need to make conditionally join. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517794/conditional-join-in-sql-server), but I dont know that how can I incorporate for my need. I want to show TaskName and Joined Table Record's Name field.

Any Help?

Comment: But what do you want to show as your result? The task plus what? A user is not a group and a group is not a location. So you just show a name (which is either user name or group name or location name)? Or what else?

Comment: Yes, I want to show name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do a left join and give you the first name it finds using [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
SELECT Task.*, COALESCE([User].Name, [Group].Name, Location.Name) AS Name
FROM Task
LEFT JOIN  [User] 
    ON [User].Id = Task.AssigneeId
    AND Task.AssigneeType = 0
LEFT JOIN  [Group] 
    ON [Group].Id = Task.AssigneeId
    AND Task.AssigneeType = 1
LEFT JOIN Location  
    ON Location.Id = Task.AssigneeId
    AND Task.AssigneeType = 2
```

Comment: What If one of the table does not have name field and we want to get some other field from it, e.g. description?

Comment: Then just change the contents of the COALESCE to, for example, `Location.Description`

Comment: I am getting Null in NAME field after executing query

Comment: That would suggest that the join is not returning a row for any of the values.

Comment: In other words, `Task.AssigneeId` doesn't match any user, group or location.

Comment: It should return the rows because i have related data in the tables.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: User: id = 15,Name = "David",
Group: id = 27,Name="Sales", 
Location: id = 542,Name = "Sharjah",

Task: Id =1 , Name = "abc", AssigneeType = 0, AssigneeID = 15,
Task: Id =1 , Name = "abc", AssigneeType = 1, AssigneeID = 27,
Task: Id =1 , Name = "abc", AssigneeType = 2, AssigneeID = 542,

Comment: And you have a row in Task table with AssigneeId = 15?

Comment: See my comment for example data.

Comment: Yes I have row with assigneeId =15

Comment: I don't get why you ask all these questions then accept another answer that is the same as mine?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join a table or not. You must join all tables. So you will outer join the three tables getting only one match. Then show that match with COALESCE.

```
select t.*, coalesce(u.name, g.name, l.name) as name
from task t
left join user u on t.assigneetype = 0 and t.assigneeid = u.id
left join [group] g on t.assigneetype = 1 and t.assigneeid = g.id
left join location l on t.assigneetype = 2 and t.assigneeid = l.id;
```

EDIT: I've corrected my answer and replaced backticks with brackets. Different dbms use different symbols in order to use reserved words such as 'GROUP' for table names. In SQL Server this should be brackets rather than backticks. However, it is always a bad idea to use reserved words for table names and columns, so you might want to change this, if you can.

Comment: Haha pretty much identical to my answer. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: @DavidG: But you were faster, and not only that: In order to use reserved words as table names, one has to use brackets not backticks in SQL Server, as your query correctly shows.

Comment: What If one of the table does not have name field and we want to get some other field from it, e.g. description?

Comment: Then use that. Either: `coalesce(u.name, g.description, l.name) as name` or `coalesce(u.name, l.name) as name, g.description as description`.